# SQL select 3 bests scores and other data for each user order by scores

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.3

May be you can help me.
I would like to display an Hall of Fame From my table with rank.
But i would like to select about **Difficulty** choice, 3 bests **Score** for each **Pseudo** in limit to 25 rows maximum order by **Score** desc.
And for each, display all information in row.

I use MariaDB 10.3.31. My Table named 'Loopz'

| Id | Pseudo | Score | Difficulty | Duration | PiecesPerMinute | LoopsPerMinute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Thy | 1333 | 1 | 42932 | 44.00 | 1.33 |
| 2 | P0lux | 1433 | 1 | 43222 | 46.33 | 1.50 |
| 3 | Sky | 600 | 1 | 25348 | 20.28 | 0.88 |
| 4 | Thy | 2500 | 1 | 53124 | 46.94 | 2.05 |
| 5 | Alex | 1200 | 0 | 21000 | 30.35 | 1.23 |
| 6 | Thy | 4200 | 1 | 60652 | 48.17 | 2.24 |
| 7 | P0lux | 3364 | 1 | 52734 | 39.37 | 1.96 |

etc...

i Try this

```
SELECT r.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        r.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Pseudo
                          ORDER BY r.Score DESC) rn
    FROM Loopz r
) r
WHERE r.rn <= 3 and Difficulty=1
ORDER BY r.Score DESC;
```

But i don't understand why it's missing some data. Some Pseudo are note selected, and some time display only 2 best scores...

Best regards

Comment: Have you used `LIMIT 3` ? instead `r.rn <= 3`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for. I've used GROUP_CONCAT to put the 3 scores on one row. I haven't applied the filter Difficulty = 1 because you have already said that you don't see all the rows that you want.
The first sort is  `ORDER BY Difficulty DESC` and we have `LIMIT 25`. This means that as soon you have 25 persons with Difficulty = 1 there will not be anyone shown with Difficulty 0.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Loopz (
>   Id int,
>   Pseudo VARCHAR(25), 
>   Score   int,
>   Difficulty int, 
>   Duration int,
>   PiecesPerMinute decimal(5,2),   
>   LoopsPerMinute decimal(5,2)
>   );
> ```

> ```
> insert into Loopz values
> (1,'Thy',1333,1,42932,44.00,1.33),
> (2,'P0lux',1433,1,43222,46.33,1.50),
> (3,'Sky',600,1,25348,20.28,0.88),
> (4,'Thy',2500,1,53124,46.94,2.05),
> (5,'Alex',1200,0,21000,30.35,1.23),
> (6,'Thy',4200,1,60652,48.17,2.24),
> (7,'P0lux',3364,1,52734,39.37,1.96);
> ```

> ```
> WITH ranking as
> (SELECT
>   Pseudo,
>   Score,
>   Difficulty,
>   Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY Pseudo ORDER BY SCORE DESC) rn
> FROM Loopz)
> SELECT
>   Pseudo,
>   GROUP_CONCAT(Score ORDER BY Score) Scores,
>   MAX(Difficulty) Difficulty
> FROM ranking
> WHERE rn < 4
> GROUP BY Pseudo
> ORDER BY 
>   Difficulty DESC,
>   MAX(Score) DESC
> LIMIT 25;
> ```
>
> ```
> Pseudo | Scores         | Difficulty
> :----- | :------------- | ---------:
> Thy    | 1333,2500,4200 |          1
> P0lux  | 1433,3364      |          1
> Sky    | 600            |          1
> Alex   | 1200           |          0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=622c35454ae847e54e686dd5a188d88b)*